# Unable to run class's functions inside a particular function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, oop, angular8

I am using inside my template HTML on a custom component:

```html
<foo ... (click)="doSth(foo)" ...></foo>
```

Then, in the controller I am calling a function belonging to the class of this particular object

```
class Foo {
      ...

      getWhatever(){
          ...
      }
}
```

```
doSth(foo: Foo) {
     foo.getWhatever();
     ....
```

At compile time, my IDE doesn't complain about anything. However, at runtime when I explicitly make that function to be executed I got:

```
FooListComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: foo.getWhatever is not a function
```

Doing a debugging, I see clear that it is not a Foo instance, instead is just a plain Object. If I try to do a cast or whatever similar nothing can help me to retrieve it like a Foo instance.

My guess is that it is treated as an Object coming from the template, should I do something like Instantiation Loader or similar?

Comment: Could you give a [mre]? Is `getWhatever` the same as `getFirstSectionCode`? How do these pieces fit together?

Comment: What is the foo argument in the template? A reference to an id? #foo?

Comment: @stachcoder foo is an object belonging to class, it is coming from a Service that retrieves this instance; @ jonrsharpe yes I have edited the post sorry and thx

Comment: Any chance it's coming from the HttpClient? In which case, see everything I linked from https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25401 - of course it's just a plain object, TS *doesn't exist* at runtime and that's what JSON parses to.

Comment: Yes, it is coming from HttpClient...

Comment: Please note [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response), then: *"Use an interface rather than a class; a response cannot be automatically converted to an instance of a class."* Unless you have explicit code to instantiate the class, it'll be a plain object.

Comment: It happens with interfaces as well, maybe you say something correct in terms, that I usually mapped the retrieved object to the correct class. However I am using ngrx data so I may do something wrong

Comment: This is why a [mre] is helpful; you've shown none of that.

Answer (score 1):

based on the comments, you need to be mapping your response into a class instance to access class methods:

```
this.http.get('foourl').pipe(map(fooResponse => new Foo(fooResponse))
```

this should get your code working, but it's questionable is this is a great design decision in general as using classes and class methods tends to cause a lot of pain in a javascript environment as stringifying and parsing loses all of your class functionality. I tend to prefer functional methods / style.